# Registros por mes y año en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en Mysql  tipo:

```
Usuarios:
- usuario
- password
- email
- fecharegistro
```

Necesito hacer una consulta que me traiga todos los registros por año y por mes. He seguido un ejemplo en internet (porque no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo y de como funciona) y lo curioso es que me arroja los años y meses como los necesito, pero no me cuenta ningún registro. Me gustaría saber si me pueden ayudar indicándome en donde estoy comentiendo el error:

```
SELECT Y,m, COUNT(fecharegistro) AS registros
FROM (
  SELECT Y, m
  FROM
    (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
    (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months) ym
  LEFT JOIN usuarios
  ON ym.y = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(fecharegistro))
     AND ym.m = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(fecharegistro))
WHERE
  (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
  OR
  (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
GROUP BY y, m
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y en registros que debes mostrar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu último where creo que esta de mas, ya que en el where de tu subconsulta ya hace la relación con mes y año de la fecha de registro

prueba quitando el el siguiente where

```
WHERE
  (y=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
  OR
  (y<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
```

o puedes prueba con esta otra consulta

```
SELECT y,m,count(*) as registros FROM 
(SELECT YEAR(InvoiceDate) as y, MONTH(InvoiceDate) as m
  FROM Invoices 
  ) as t
GROUP BY y,m order by y desc,m desc
```

Comment: vaya, muchas gracias Juan Carlos, me sirvió de mucho.